Телеграмм бот на aiogram не работает
Я мега-новичек в пайтоне.
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message

bot = Bot(token=%ТОКЕН%)
dp = Dispatcher()



@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def welcome(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Привет!')


async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

Когда запускаю ошибок нет, а бот не отвечает на сообщение /start
